# RavenDb Skips items when there are no filtering conditions

Tags: .net, nosql, ravendb

I want to retrieve all documents of some type by the following query:

```
var customers = documentSession.Query<Customer>()
```

but in this case I get only 1 result (while there are 78 of them). If I add some filtering condition which is always true, I get all 78 documents:

```
var customers = documentSession.Query<Customer>().Where(c => c.Id != null).ToList();
```

I guess it is a bug.

**Update.** RavenDb Build 531

**Update 2**

Daniel and Oren, sorry for the delay.

I have prepared a sample application. You can download it here: http://www.2shared.com/file/AGIAR5UA/RavenDbSampleAppication.html

There is test NUnit project which references SkazhiKazinoNet.Data.Model.dll where model is defined. I just added package with last RavenDb and imported data from dump4.raven (you can find it in packages/Raven/tools) by Raven.Smuggler.

Comment: Idsa,
That doesn't sound right, can you provide a failing test?

Comment: @AyendeRahien, please look at Update2

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that there's no such bug (in any recent version) because of a couple of reasons:

- this would be such a huge one, many applications would break
- there are a fair amount of unit-tests that would fail

To help you identify the problem - can you provide a failing test?

Please make sure that you call `.ToList()` on your first query too.

Comment: I also was surprised... I have cleared Data folder and than improted data by Raven.Smuggler and now it returns zero documents instead of one :) The version with Where still returns all items.

Comment: That sounds interesting. Can you put together a small sample application or a test and upload on github?

Answer (score 2):

You were right, the database inside your archive was corrupted.

I could reproduce the error. The query:

> curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/indexes/dynamic/Casinos

returns

```
{"Results":[],"Includes":[],"IsStale":false,"IndexTimestamp":"2011-12-31T02:19:51.2660000","TotalResults":0,"SkippedResults":0,"IndexName":"LastComments","IndexEtag":"00000000-0000-0100-0000-000000000078"}
```

Then I deleted all indexes and restarted the server. Now the query returns correct results.
So, after you delete all your indexes and recreate them, it should work on your machine too.

I'm sorry but I cannot provide any further information on that, maybe Oren can.

Comment: What do you mean by "remove all indexes"? Remove Indexes folder?

Comment: Inside management studio, open up every index one by one and delete them.